# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 to type System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'

Tags: c#, winforms

I download data from my database and load it to datagridview depending on situation:

```
_bottleClientQuery.GetRestClientsReadModel().ToList()  //get IEnumerable<RestCLientReadModel>
_bottleClientQuery.GetSertClientsReadModel().ToList()  //get IEnumerable<SertCLientReadModel>
```

then getting data i am loading to `datagridview`:

```
public void LoadDataToGrid(object model) => grid.DataSource = model;
```

All works, nbevertheless i want to make some filters therefore i did this:

```
private void txtKlientFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var bd = (BindingSource)grid.DataSource;
     var dt = (DataTable)bd.DataSource;
     dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like '%{0}%'", txtKlientFilter.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
     grid.Refresh();
}
```

When i start typoing into `textbox` i get:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Appi.InfrastructureLayer.Query.Client.RestCLientReadModel]' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'.'
```

Comment: Well, you set, e.g., a `List<RestCLientReadModel>` as the DataSource (as an `Object`? No generics available here? No overloading?). How could you cast it to BindingSource? Maybe add a BindingSource, set it's DataSource to your List, then use the BindingSource as the DataSource of your DGV. It's not clear why this BindingSource is supposed to have a DataTable as DataSource. If you use a BD, use its `Filter`, eventually. Otherwise explain where these objects (BindingSource and DataTable) come from.

Comment: I mean dont know i am just loading this way and it works. My target is to now filter those data so i try to do as in txtKlientFilter_TextChanged. It could be diffrent of course.

Comment: Right, but you cannot pull a BindingSource (and a DataTable) out of the hat like that. Assign your source of data (the `List<Something>`) to a `BindingSource.DataSource`, then use the BindingSource as the DataSource of your DGV. After that you can use the BindingSource properties / methods. See the [BindingSource.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter) Property, for example. You can store the BindingSource as a Field and access it directly, or cast: `var bds = [DataGridView.DataSource] as BindingSource`. Then use it.

Comment: @Jimi can you post as an answer as you explained showing code based on my one? I still can get it to work.

Comment: No, I cannot. The question is closed as duplicate. The dupe uses LINQ on a `IEnumerable<T>`. You can ignore the dupe and use a BindingSource (which is way better if you have other bound Controls, the duplicate won't help you at all), or do the ~same thing.